# Adding two very large numbers represented as base64-encoded strings

Tags: php, math, base64

I have very large numbers, and decided to represent them with base64 strings in php.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a library (or built in system) to work with base64 as numbers (aka add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc)?

Comment: why? what's wrong with the numbers as is?

Comment: Do you understand *what* base-64 strings represent?

Comment: I do, I'm not talking about `base64_encode`, but base 64 numbers.

Comment: Even Mathematica only handles through Base 36.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it does not make much sense to speak about operations on numbers in one specific base or another.  Rather, you decode your numbers to a more useful or generalized representation (e.g. a string of decimal digits) and then perform work, re-encoding your result for storage as necessary.

The [Math_BigInteger](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger) library facilitates this.  You will of course still have to first decode your base64 data to a base usable by the class, i.e., binary, decimal, or hexidecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I thought working with base64 (because the number is already in that format) would be a more optimized solution, but it sounds like that just isn't a possibility.

Comment: It would be possible to write your own library to do this, but it's very unlikely that one already exists as it would only be marginally useful.  The additional performance overhead of initial and final conversion should be negligible since it's only an additional `2n` total steps, and you have the added benefit of not having to write your own arithmetic library!

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). The problem is that you want to add arbitrary-precision numbers. For that, you should use an arbitrary precision math package, such as [BC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php). There's no point representing them in base64 unless there's an implementation of arithmetic for those, which as far as you know there isn't.